# How deselect row in grid of devexpress - winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have one grid with property MultiSelected set to false, and I need to clear the selection in the current grid when the user clicks a button. I read in the documentation about two methods, but it doesn't work when the user can only select one row.

Here is my attempt to solve this:

```
gridView1.ClearSelection();
foreach (var i in gridView1.GetSelectedRows())
   gridView1.UnselectRow(i);
```

I hope someone help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When multiple selection is off, the grid does not allow unfocusing a row and always contains a focused row. See this [issue](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q347126) for some additional information.

The [GetSelectedRows](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetSelectedRowstopic) and [ClearSelection](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ClearSelectiontopic) documentation clearly states that these do nothing if multi-selection is disabled.

There are a couple of sample projects in the support center regarding row selection:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E13
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E135

The best place to ask for support for DevExpress related questions is their [Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/). If you describe what you are trying to achieve, they always respond quickly and helpfully.